# A generic way to deal with intermittent non-numerical values in arrays

Tags: numerical-value

Sometimes when dealing with arrays with intermittent non-numerical values (e.g., `NaN`s imported from external sources), the common arithmetic functions (e.g., `Median`) may break annoyingly.
Although it's possible to replace those `NaN`s with `Indeterminate` and then carefully remove them before applying the arithmetic functions, such operations are rather tedious compared to other computing environments (e.g., `numpy`) where similar functions would quietly ignore those `NaN`s and produce results.

I'm wondering if we can create a similar pure numeric environment in Mathematica that can do such jobs more easily?

For example, for an arbitrary array generated using the code below:

```
arNaN = Array[
  RandomChoice[{RandomReal[], Indeterminate}] &, {4, 2, 3, 5}]
```

How can we apply the common arithmetic functions (e.g., `Median`, `Quartiles`, etc.) without deliberately removing the non-numerical items?

For people who are also familiar with `numpy`/`pandas`, I would like something similar there like `numpy.nanmedian`/`pandas.DataFrame.median` which can quietly ignore `NaN` values.

Comment: Replace those values with `Missing[]` rather than `Indeterminate`, then combine those numeric functions with `DeleteMissing`. For instance, instead of `Median` try `Median@*DeleteMissing`.

Comment: Yes, this could be one approach. But I said in the question, the `Missing`-based approach usually needs one to deliberately specify the levels where `DeleteMissing` should be applied and would create ragged arrays, leading to failure of common arithmetic functions. So it's not an ideal approach for dealing with regular arrays of arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: how about `Block[{Indeterminate = Nothing}, 
 arNaN /. a : {___?NumericQ} :> Median[a]]`?

Comment: thanks @kglr, but this approach is not ideal either as it only applies to the second to last level.

Answer (score 4):

`Query` adds automatic handling for `Missing` to many built-in functions. It's not always fool-proof, but it deals with easy cases quite well:

```
Query[Median] @ {1., 2., Missing[]}
```

> 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Define first the test data:

```
arNaN = Array[RandomChoice[{RandomReal[], Indeterminate}] &, {4, 2, 3, 5}];
```

Now we can redefine `Indeterminate` e.g. as `Sequence` what has the effect, that all `Indeterminate` disappear:

```
Unprotect[Indeterminate]
Indeterminate = Sequence[]
Protect[Indeterminate]
```

You can now say e.g.

```
arNaN
```

[image]

and use `arNaN` as a purly numeric array.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work and will break the system definition of `Indeterminate`: all code using `Indeterminate` will lose the their calculation nature. more dangerously, `arNaN = Array[RandomChoice[{RandomReal[], Indeterminate}] &, {4, 2, 3, 5}];` won't produce the required array for testing with mixed numerical and non-numerical values but always produces a regular numerical array.

Answer (score 0):

Edits:

1. sorry the code was done in a rush; a correction is now added.
2. tests for normal numerical arrays are added.
3. release the restriction on `ArrayQ` test so the function can be applied to `Association`s as well.

---

After several trials, I seem to find a way to deal with this (not very elegant though):

```
Clear[nanFun]
nanFun[x_/; ArrayDepth[x] == 1, fun_] := 
 fun[Select[x, NumericQ]]
nanFun[x_/; ArrayDepth[x] >= 2, fun_] := 
 nanFun[#, fun] & /@ Transpose[x]
nanFun[fun : (_Function | _Symbol)] := nanFun[#, fun] &
```

Some tests for `arNaN = Array[RandomChoice[{RandomReal[], Indeterminate}] &, {4, 2, 3, 5}]` (results may vary):

1. `nanFun[Median][arNaN]`: `{{0.545609, 0.78447, 0.343546}, {0.293374, 0.243323,  0.183473}, {0.283449, 0.459367, 0.615839}, {0.686463, 0.157145,  0.412199}}`;
2. `nanFun[Quartiles][arNaN]// Dimensions`: `{4, 3, 3}`.

Then in scenarios where only numeric values should be appreciated, one just needs to replace the normal `fun` with `nanFun[fun]` (e.g., `Median` -> `nanFun[Median]`).

Also, for pure numerical arrays, `nanFun[fun]` and `fun` should produce identical results.
More tests:

```
arNum = RandomReal[10, {2, 4, 5}];
With[{fun = #}, fun[arNum] == nanFun[fun][arNum]] & /@ {Median, 
  Quartiles, Skewness}
(*out: {True, True, True}*)
```

Comments/suggestions are welcome.